# Перенос сайта с хостинга, на локальный сервер, CMS Modx

Tags: веб-сервер, denwer, cms

Возникла проблема при переносе сайта с сервера на локальный сервер. Панель администартора доступна, все работает, а сам сайт при просмотре пустой экран выдает, пыталась сбросить кэш не помогло? затем проверяла пути их также правила на нужные. В чем возможная причина?На хостинге использовалось виртуальное окружение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте конфиги апача (или что там у Вас) и на сервере и на локалхосте, возможно проблема в настройках. Так же проверьте вывод phpinfo() на сервере и на localhost, должны увидеть текущие настройки и подключенные модули. Соответственно приводите настройку localhoct идентично серверу.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема может быть в установленом ПО на локальной машине.Нужно сверить версии ПО сервера и локальной машины.